# Stop current audio file to prevent multiple files simultaneously

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm trying to make a sort of soundboard app in Android Studio. For now I have three buttons: 2 of them play specific audio files and the other one stops the audio. Everything works except if you play one audio file while another one is going already they both play at the same time and the stop button no longer works on either of them. You have to exit the app. I cannot figure out how to get the first file to quit before playing the second. Here is my code so far:

```
package com.something.example.com;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button startLie, startTruth,
            stopScan;
    private MediaPlayer play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startLie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startlie);
        startLie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.lie_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        stopScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopScan);
        stopScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play.stop();
                };
            });

        startTruth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starttruth);
        startTruth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.truth_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to disable music button 2 and leave only stop button clickable when music button 1 is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have been able to finally get this to work. I basically created a stopPlaying function (placed at the end of my file. and then called it every time before the audio files play. Here's the code again, and this time with a couple more buttons.

```
package com.something.example;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button startLie, startTruth,
            startIdiot, startGenius, stopScan;
    private MediaPlayer play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startLie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startlie);
        startLie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.lie_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        stopScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopScan);
        stopScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play.stop();
                };
            });

        startTruth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starttruth);
        startTruth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.truth_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        startIdiot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startidiot);
        startIdiot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.idiot_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        startGenius = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgenius);
        startGenius.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.genius_detector);
                play.start();
                play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                        play.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (play != null) {
            play.stop();
            play.release();
            play = null;
        }
    }
```